# с++ Как удалить значения контейнера QList<QString> вложенного внутрь контейнера QMultiMap<int,QList<QString>>

Tags: c++, qt, контейнеры

Есть два контейнера: `QMultiMap<int, QList<QString>> A` и, `QList<QString> B`, причем второй контейнер `QList` создается и удаляется динамически. Вопрос такой: как удалить значения контейнера `QList<QString>` вложенного внутрь этого `QMultiMap<int, QList<QString>>`?

Comment: A[i].clear(); // QList останется в мапе, только будет пустой